# Investing with Masser money

Tags: halacha, money, maaser-tithes

I'm taking off a 10'th of my weekly income and putting it in a separate *Masser* account which I later (end of the month) use to pay *Tzadukah*.
Am I allowed to invest these money in the meantime?

And if so, am I required to give the full profit for *Tzadukah* or can I just add a 10'th of the profit to the original amount?

We can look at it as if I'm paying *Masser* once a month. I'm just putting the money weekly on a side. Or perhaps by putting it aside it's already considered *Meus Masser* and the full profit belongs for *Tzadukah*.

Furthermore, if I loose money, am I required to add the difference since it was invested with *Masser* money, or again, I'm only required to pay a 10'th of the closing amount the end of the month?

Comment: Don't forget to ask your rabbi any practical questions, using this site only as background info.

Comment: I don't understand "I'm only required to pay a 10'th of the closing amount the end of the month". Shouldn't that be "I'm only required to pay the closing amount at the end of the month, plus nine tenths of the amount lost"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in 259:1 -  [סימן רנט - הנודר ואינו יודע מה נדר ודין אמירה לגבוה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_36.html#HtmpReportNum0012_L2)  - states:

> **א:** הָאוֹמֵר: סֶלַע זוֹ לִצְדָקָה, אוֹ שֶׁאוֹמֵר: הֲרֵי עָלַי סֶלַע לִצְדָקָה, וְהִפְרִישׁוֹ, עַד שֶׁלֹּא בָּא לְיַד הַגַּבַּאי יָכוֹל לְשַׁנּוֹתוֹ, בֵּין לִלְווֹתוֹ לְעַצְמוֹ בֵּין לְהַלְווֹתוֹ לַחֲבֵרוֹ, וְיִפְרַע אַחֵר תַּחְתָּיו. הגה: וְכֵן אִם הִקְדִּישׁ כֵּלִים, יָכוֹל לְמָכְרָם לִפְנֵי ג' בְּקִיאִים בְּשׁוּמָא, וְנוֹתֵן דְּמֵיהֶם לִצְדָקָה. (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם הַגָּהוֹת מָרְדְּכַי דִּכְתֻבּוֹת) . מִשֶּׁבָּא לְיַד גַּבַּאי, אָסוּר לִלְווֹתוֹ, בֵּין לוֹ בֵּין לְאַחֵר בֵּין לַגַּבַּאי. וְאִם הָיָה הֲנָאָה לַעֲנִיִּים בְּעִכּוּב הַמָּעוֹת בְּיַד הַגַּבַּאי, כְּדֵי  לְעַשׂוֹת לַאֲחֵרִים לִתֵּן, הֲרֵי הַגַּבַּאי מֻתָּר לִלְווֹתָם וּלְפָרְעָם.‏
>  ***הגה***: דְּאֵין הַצְּדָקָה כְּהֶקְדֵּשׁ, וּמֻתָּר לֵהָנוֹת מִמֶּנָּהּ. (טוּר) . **וְאֵין נוֹשְׂאִין וְנוֹתְנִין בִּצְדָקָה הָעוֹמֶדֶת לְחַלֵּק לַעֲנִיִּים, כִּי אִם כֶּסֶף בְּכֶסֶף וְכַיּוֹצֵא בוֹ, שֶׁמָּא יָבֹאוּ עֲנִיִּים וְלא יִהְיֶה לָהֶם מָעוֹת לְחַלֵּק. אֲבָל צְדָקָה שֶׁאֵינָהּ עוֹמֶדֶת לְחַלֵּק, רַק הַקֶּרֶן יְהֵא קַיָּם וְיֹאכְלוּ הַפֵּרוֹת, שָׁרֵי.** (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם סה''ת שַׁעַר מ''ו ח''ד ס''ח וְהַגָּהוֹת מַיְמוֹנִי) . **וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין**.‏

You asked:

> Am I allowed to invest these money in the meantime?

That depends on your intent when tithing. If you intended to distribute the money to the needy, then you may not do business with it, nor invest it.

> And if so, am I required to give the full profit for Tzadukah or can I just add a 10'th of the profit to the original amount?

If your intent was to invest the amount and give the profits to the needy, then you have to give the entire amount of the profit to the needy "forever" (or until you liquidate the investment and give the entire sum remaining to the needy).

The Remo says that that is the prevalent custom.

> Furthermore, if I loose money, am I required to add the difference since it was invested with Masser money, or again, I'm only required to pay a 10'th of the closing amount the end of the month?

The Shulchan Aruch doesn't say, but it would make sense that since it's treated as "their money", and they get all the profits, they should also suffer the losses.

P.S. Tithing all depends on custom - Minhag - and what your original intent is.

<sup>**Reminder**: Ask for LOR for a practical ruling. This is for reference only. Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your Rabbi.</sup>